# select where in(Float, .....)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select some values from mysql with the next sentence:

```
SELECT 
  id, lead_id, form_id, field_number, value 
FROM 
  wp_rg_lead_detail 
WHERE 
  field_number IN (6.3, 6.6, 11, 12, 17, 14) 
ORDER BY 
  lead_id, field_number
```

the field field_number is a float and the select is listing just the 11, 12, 17 and 14 fields but not values from the 6.3 and 6.6

What is wrong with the sentence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query. The problem is that `float` is not precise type. Use `decimal` instead (or change the query to something like `... WHERE (field_number BETWEEN 6.2999 AND 6.3001) OR (field_number BETWEEN 6.5999 AND 6.6001 OR ()...` )

Comment: sorry, no parenthesis... Fixing , it should be `between 6.2999 and 6.30001 `

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that 6.3 and 6.6 are not actually stored in your table. Computers cannot perfectly represent most fractional values. When the value stored is compared to 6.3 or 6.6, it does not match, even though it looks like it should. The difference might be at the 9th or 10th decimal place, which you won't normally see.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

If you need to exactly compare the values, make them integers or decimals. If nothing will ever have more than 1 number to the right of the decimal point, you can multiply all values by 10 to only work with integers, for example.

Comment: "make them integers" --- or decimals

Comment: the table belongs to a wordpress plugin and when I change the field to decimal it stops working, I need to get the values as float.